# Trying to implement Substrate client on IoT, any suggestions?

Tags: transactions, no-std

I'm trying to implement a Substrate client on IoT, to send a basic extrinsic that stores as an example, a key-value. This code needs to run on ARM or ESP32 kinds of chips.

Are there any suggestions on which library to use?

The [polkadot_api_cpp](https://github.com/usetech-llc/polkadot_api_cpp) is too old because it supports only up to substrate metadata V7.
Also, I've tried to `no_std` the Rust [substrate-api-client](https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client) library [without success](https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client/issues/190).

I'm considering building a C client to build/send a transaction to Substrate, but I really wanna be sure that there's no alternative.

Comment: I'm not familiar with subxt enough to know how feasible `no_std` support is, but there's an old issue for it https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/159. Maybe you could chime in there. The hard part about creating a substrate client is that it needs to be "dynamic" in order to be useful long-term, i.e. it most generate its API based on substrate's chain metadata. This might also be of interest to you: https://www.cyrilfougeray.com/2020/12/14/leger-rust-wallet-1.html

Comment: try the go-substrate-rpc-client, it's platform-independent.

Comment: @André Thanks for the issue link ! I'm aware that the client has to have this "dynamic" structure (using metadata) to adapt the new futur chain spec.
My goal is to first have a strictly (chain) specific implementation first, but maybe that isn't best idea ?
It's a shame Rust/Substrate makes it difficult to target IoT.

Comment: @ChinoChang Thanks for the tip, unfortunately I've no experience in Go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think making subxt be no std compatible would seem to be the best way to go.
https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/208

No one has yet given it a crack with a PR, but all the on chain code is no_std so it's probably doable. (There are a few other IOT parachain/threads so maybe check with them too - https://parachains.info/details/nodle_iot and https://www.radom.network/ )

Answer (score 2):

You can see a list of tools here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/v3/integration/client-libraries
- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate#tools

Note that some are actively maintained, others are not.